# Css styling without !important - how to do this?

Tags: html, css

I want to style my `a` item in `li` list by adding to it specific class called `.list-click`.

There is my code that is not working unless I use `!important`.

I want to avoid using this so maybe there is someone who know how to solve my problem. I am not using any js script which could overwrite my css or sth like this.

```css
.portfolio-menu {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-menu li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.portfolio-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
.portfolio-menu li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.portfolio-menu li a:focus {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.list-click {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-menu">
  <li><a href="#portfolio" class="list-click">all</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">logo</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">icons</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [be more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

`.portfolio-menu li a` is more specific than `.list-click` and so it will always win no matter what order you place it in the style sheet.

```
.portfolio-menu li .list-click {
    color: red
}
```

Example:

```css
.portfolio-menu{
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-menu li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.portfolio-menu li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.portfolio-menu li a:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.portfolio-menu li a:focus{
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.portfolio-menu li .list-click{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-menu">
  <li><a href="#portfolio" class="list-click">all</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">logo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">icons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a more preferred / specific selector for `list-click` and that will work:

```
.portfolio-menu li a.list-click{
  color: red;
}
```

snippet below:

```css
.portfolio-menu{
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-menu li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.portfolio-menu li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}

.portfolio-menu li a:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.portfolio-menu li a:focus{
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.portfolio-menu li a.list-click{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-menu">
  <li><a href="#portfolio" class="list-click">all</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">logo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">icons</a></li>
</ul>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code without `!important` and it will work:

```
.portfolio-menu li a.list-click{
  color: red;
}
```